# Setting up a local host and getting a connection refused error

Tags: apache, web-hosting

After following the instructions to set up a personal server with the native Apache software on a OS X 10.6.8 (SnowLeopard), and After modifying the apache2.config file as per the directions, typing the following in a browser:

```
     http:// localhost
```

(either Chrome or Safari) returns a connection refused error.

What is to be done?  Taking the firewall up or down doesn't change the localhost connection error.

telnet returns this:

```
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
    Trying ::1...
    telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
    Trying fe80::1...
    telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused
    telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

netstat among a host of other data returned:

```
    udp4       0      0  localhost.64790        *.*
```

typing netstat -i in the terminal returns:

```
    Name  Mtu   Network       Address            Ipkts Ierrs    Opkts Oerrs  Coll
    lo0   16384 <Link#1>                           954     0      954     0     0  
    lo0   16384 localhost   ::1                    954     -      954     -     -  
    lo0   16384 localhost   fe80:1::1              954     -      954     -     -  
    lo0   16384 127           localhost            954     -      954     -     -
```

The curious thing is that the browsers read local HTML and other local files normally.  For example entering:

```
file:///Library/Webserver/Documents/index.html.en
```

returns **"It works!"**

But this doesn't resolve the problem of the browsers not responding to the local host.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE

So I got the localhost to work but the links were broken when I moved the files to the correct directory.
Once I got the links fixed, typing `localhost` in Safari caused the compass to fly out of the browser!

Network Utility returns

```
Port Scanning host:  127.0.0.1
    Open TCP Port 80:    http
```

The error_log has this warning:

```
Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSlSessionCache]
```

The ssl_module is included in the LoadModule section.

typing `/usr/sbin/httpd` in the Terminal gives me the following error:

```
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80  
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

and after modifying the configuration file to listen to 8080 the computer returns another error:

```
(13)Permission denied: httpd: could not open error log file /private/var/log/apache2/error_log.  
Unable to open logs
```

A manuel by Julie Meloni states:

```
This problem can arise if the user who built and installed  
Apache is different from the user trying to run it.
```

However that is not the case in this instance.  The manual offers no explanation as how to solve this problem.

After checking the permissions with `ls -l /etc/apache2/httpd.conf` The terminal returns:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 18973 Dec 7 22:49 /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

As far as I can tell this suggests the file doesn't have permission to execute.  After running a `chmod 755` the computer reported that this operation was not permitted.

I have the Internet sharing preferences turned on so that isn't the issue.

using `curl http://127.0.0.1` in the Terminal returns the HTML code for shorter files, but with longer files it only returns the HTML file selectively and a strange error where it repeats the MacBook owner's first name multiple times across the screen.

Typing `tail /var/log/apache2/error_log` in the terminal returns:

```
[warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist  
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist  
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist  
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist 
[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[notice] Digest: done
[notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) PHP/5.4.45 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zg mod_perl/2.0.7 Perl/v5.16.2 configured -- resuming normal operations.
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you start apache? Is it configured to listen on port 80? Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: Yes, apache was started and  already loaded, and it is at port 80.  All the documentation that I have read says that the browser (Chrome) should respond to the localhost command.

Comment: Which interface is it listening on? localhost? Try `http://127.0.0.1`.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1 refused connection also.

Comment: So, which interface is it listening on? Not localhost. Try the hostname of the server, or it's IP address.

Comment: Safari also refuses the connection

Comment: The IP address gives the same response as the localhost.  How do you check the interface?

Comment: It's nothing to do with browser. Your apache server is not listening where you think it is. Is it running on the same machine? Have you checked logs?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Apache Error Logs are empty.  Yes, the browser, and Apache are on the same machine but the System Administrator is unreachable.

Comment: Obviously difficult to diagnose in this forum - and the question should probably have been posted at https://serverfault.com/. Can you try connecting with `curl http://localhost`? Also check whether there might be a firewall.

Comment: `I get a connection refused error` That implies something _is_ listening on that port, but it's telling you to go away.

Comment: Chrome states specifically:          

        This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.                ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED   

 And Safari says  
                  "Failed to open page"  Safari can't connect to the server.  Safari can't open the page "http:localhost/" because Safari can't connect to the server "localhost".    

But it takes internal HTML files.

Comment: @JohnGordon:  Connection refused implies nothing certain regarding the listen state of the host:port. Either apache is not listening on that host:port (not running, using a different port etc.), or possibly a firewall is blocking connections. Impossible to tell without access to the server.

Comment: Voting to close. Should be asked on serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.grep process using netstats command make sure that apache is using port 80 (ipv4 and ipv6)
2. check your apache conf if lisner ip set to either 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 
3. telnet localhost 80 
4. try other browsers firefox or safari

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I don't think this answers the question. The grep analytics was helpful but it gave me so much information, that I am still trying to go through it.   The configuration file sets the listener by default to port 80 and not to IP addresses.    telnet and http request to port 80 get the same results.  Other browsers return the same response.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to get the local host working more or less after spending a lot of time trying to make sense of the output coming out of the Network Utility and trying to find what variable to include with netscape|greps in the terminal.  I'm still not sure what was causing the error.

I followed the instructions found on this youtube video by Kyle Gadds of BootPress:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78wFR5Rp_Mw
```

I edited the apache configuration file to include:

```
 /User/[YOUR_USER_NAME]/Sites/www
```

in the file, and I changed the AllowOverrides flags.
Then I noticed the Sites folder was missing from the system and the php.ini file was empty.
Making a new Sites folder is easy.  Just go to the User directory and have the Finder create a new folder called "Sites".
But replacing the php was more difficult.  I had to open the terminal and type

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

in the command line and this brought php.ini file back and I had to modify the permissions. Then it worked.  I hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.